# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n n^2(-2)^n}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

How would one determine the convergence of the series $ \frac{(-1)^n n^2 (-2)^n}{2^n} $ using the Divergence Test? I'm not quite sure how to simplify the expression, especially since there are two negative numbers raised to the nth power, which do not look like the examples I've seen with alternating series.

To sum it up, I would like some help with evaluating the following limit:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(-1)^n n^2(-2)^n}{2^n} $$

Comment: If you don't know how to simplify the expression I would strongly recommend to review your basics of elementary Algebra before trying to deal with questions from Calculus.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just realized that all I have to do is combine $(-1)^n$ and $(-2)^n$, which can be rewritten as $2^n$, so this term can be cancelled out with the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the $(-1)^n$ and $(-2)^n$ together to get $2^n$, and cancel that with the denominator to get $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} n^2$

Comment: But the question was about the *series*, not just the limit of the sequence of terms.

Comment: If the limit of the terms isn't $0$, then the series diverges

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as $\lim_{\to \infty}n^2 = \infty$

Comment: But the question was about the *series*, not just the limit of the sequence of terms.

Comment: Yes, and by the fact that the limit of the n-th term of a convergent sequence is zero.

Comment: Note my second comment here was a response to a now deleted comment.

Comment: $n^2 \geq \frac{1}{n}$ hence we get divergence of $\sum n^2 > \sum \frac{1}{n} = \infty$

Comment: Yes your last comment is right showing divergence by comparison with a known divergent series.